# How to assign "Edit" permission per Webform?

Tags: webforms

On Drupal 7, how can I assign the "Edit" permission per webform, beside using "Permissions per Webform"?

Comment: And what gave you idea Content Access is a way to do this? If there is some kind of manual that says you can, it probably also says how. I wouldn't expect it to be possible as webform submissions are not nodes, but there are many things I would not expect.

Comment: I'm taking over someone project. The client would like a user(1 user) to modify a particular Webform. The "Access Control(content access)" tag already setted up per page on this Drupal site, so I assume it should work on Webform. Anyway, I found there a setting on "Access Control(content access)", please see below answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

It actually can be done by "Enable per content node access control settings", which is under "Structure > Content types > Edit Webform > Access Control".